# Parse CalendarContract.Events.DURATION values

Tags: android, android-calendar

I'm querying my calendar and showing all events result.
When i'm trying to parse the value CalendarContract.Events.DURATION i'm getting a RFC2445 string format.

For example i'm getting "P15M" which I know it's 15 minutes meeting.
After digging on the internet on how to parse RFC2445 I've found some google jar [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-rfc-2445/downloads/list)

But is there any static class to parse those format?
Compiling a jar and using it only for 1 function it's not that nice...

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have had the same problem as you, dug around and found the following useful snippet somewhere. I refactored it a bit, so it will be more readable. hope it helps!

```
 public static long RFC2445ToMilliseconds(String str)
{


    if(str == null || str.isEmpty())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null or empty RFC string");

    int sign = 1;
    int weeks = 0;
    int days = 0;
    int hours = 0;
    int minutes = 0;
    int seconds = 0;

    int len = str.length();
    int index = 0;
    char c;

    c = str.charAt(0);

    if (c == '-')
    {
        sign = -1;
        index++;
    }

    else if (c == '+')
        index++;

    if (len < index)
        return 0;

    c = str.charAt(index);

    if (c != 'P')
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Duration.parse(str='" + str + "') expected 'P' at index="+ index);

    index++;
    c = str.charAt(index);
    if (c == 'T')
        index++;

    int n = 0;
    for (; index < len; index++)
    {
        c = str.charAt(index);

        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
        {
            n *= 10;
            n += ((int)(c-'0'));
        }

        else if (c == 'W')
        {
            weeks = n;
            n = 0;
        }

        else if (c == 'H')
        {
            hours = n;
            n = 0;
        }

        else if (c == 'M')
        {
            minutes = n;
            n = 0;
        }

        else if (c == 'S')
        {
            seconds = n;
            n = 0;
        }

        else if (c == 'D')
        {
            days = n;
            n = 0;
        }

        else if (c == 'T')
        {
        }
        else
            throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Duration.parse(str='" + str + "') unexpected char '" + c + "' at index=" + index);
    }

    long factor = 1000 * sign;
    long result = factor * ((7*24*60*60*weeks)
            + (24*60*60*days)
            + (60*60*hours)
            + (60*minutes)
            + seconds);

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In while loop of cursor

> String duration = "your duration";

```
        try {
            Duration d = new Duration();
            d.parse(duration);
            endMillis = startMillis + d.getMillis();
            if (debug)
                Log.d(TAG, "startMillis! " + startMillis);
            if (debug)
                Log.d(TAG, "endMillis!   " + endMillis);
            if (endMillis < startMillis) {
                continue;
            }
        } catch (DateException e) {
            if (debug)
                Log.d(TAG, "duration:" + e.toString());
            continue;
        }
```

[The class Duration is](http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/frameworks/opt/calendar/src/com/android/calendarcommon2/Duration.java)  and [also refer](http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/packages/apps/Calendar/src/com/android/calendar/EventInfoFragment.java)   line number 1487. there is parsing logic , you just need to include duration class in your source code and parse as in try block.

I hope it helps